# Add dynamically QML Page on SwipeView QML

Tags: qt, qml, qt5, swipeview

i need to add dynamically pages on swipeview.
So my code:

```
    SwipeView {
        id: viewSwipe
        width: parent.width
        height: parent.height * 0.70
        currentIndex: 0
        Component.onCompleted: {
            curIndexWitouthZero = viewSwipe.currentIndex
            curIndexWitouthZero += 1
            addPage(RecipesPhase)
        }

        onCurrentIndexChanged: {
            curIndexWitouthZero = viewSwipe.currentIndex
            curIndexWitouthZero += 1
        }

        Item {
            id: firstPage
            RecipesPhase{}
        }
    }

    PageIndicator {
        id: indicator
        interactive: true
        count: viewSwipe.count
        currentIndex: viewSwipe.currentIndex

        anchors.top: viewSwipe.bottom
        anchors.topMargin: parent.height * 0.05
        anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
    }
```

i've a button who when clicked, the event should add the pages like an Item.
My code is:

```
  MouseArea{
     anchors.fill: parent
     onClicked: {
         console.log("Cliccato additem")
         //viewSwipe.addItem(RecipesPhase)
         viewSwipe.addPage(RecipesPhase)
     }
  }
```

But nothing happened. So i've tried also:

```
     SwipeView {
        id: viewSwipe
        width: parent.width
        height: parent.height * 0.70
        currentIndex: 0
        Component.onCompleted: {
            curIndexWitouthZero = viewSwipe.currentIndex
            curIndexWitouthZero += 1
            addPage(RecipesPhase)
        }

        onCurrentIndexChanged: {
            curIndexWitouthZero = viewSwipe.currentIndex
            curIndexWitouthZero += 1
        }

        function addPage(page) {
            console.log("funzione addPage()")
           addItem(page)
           page.visible = true
        }
    }
```

and then call:

```
viewSwipe.addPage(MyPageQML)
```

but nothing happened.
So, the question is, where i'm wrong ? Thanks for the solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RecipesPhase is a component not an Item, a component is analogous to a class and an Item to an object, so the idea is to create the item dynamically. For example, I will consider that RecipesPhase is the following component:

**RecipesPhase.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.0

Rectangle {
    width: 100
    height: 100
    color: "red"
}
```

Then each time you press the mouseArea you create a RecipesPhase of a random color:

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 2.4

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Example")
    property int curIndexWitouthZero: 0

    SwipeView {
        id: viewSwipe
        width: parent.width
        height: parent.height * 0.70
        currentIndex: 0
        Component.onCompleted: {
            curIndexWitouthZero = viewSwipe.currentIndex
            curIndexWitouthZero += 1
            addPage(createPage())
        }

        onCurrentIndexChanged: {
            curIndexWitouthZero = viewSwipe.currentIndex
            curIndexWitouthZero += 1
        }

        function addPage(page) {
            console.log("funzione addPage()")
            addItem(page)
            page.visible = true
        }
        function createPage(){
            var component = Qt.createComponent("RecipesPhase.qml");
            var page = component.createObject(viewSwipe,
                                              {"color": Qt.rgba(Math.random(), Math.random(), Math.random(), Math.random())}
                                              );
            return page
        }
    }
    PageIndicator {
        id: indicator
        interactive: true
        count: viewSwipe.count
        currentIndex: viewSwipe.currentIndex
        onCurrentIndexChanged: viewSwipe.currentIndex = currentIndex

        anchors.top: viewSwipe.bottom
        anchors.topMargin: parent.height * 0.05
        anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
    }
    MouseArea{
        anchors.top: indicator.bottom
        anchors.left: parent.left
        anchors.right: parent.right
        anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
        onClicked: viewSwipe.addPage(viewSwipe.createPage())
    }
}
```